# Unhandled Rejection (AbortError): The fetching process for the media resource was aborted by the user agent at the user's request

Tags: javascript

https://onoumenon.gitbook.io/wiki/programming/tips/rtmp

```
  buildPlayer() {
    if (this.player || !this.props.stream) {
      return;
    }
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;
    this.player = flv.createPlayer({
      type: "flv",
      url: `http://localhost:8000/live/${id}.flv`
    });
    this.player.attachMediaElement(this.videoRef.current);
    this.player.load();
  }
```

I am trying to use this code to stream videos to users, but I get an error, if there are no stream and the app crashes.

> Unhandled Rejection (AbortError): The fetching process for the media resource was aborted by the user agent at the user's request.

The error is thrown when I try to execute this:

```
player.attachMediaElement(videoRef.current);
```

Is there a way to check if this line is going to throw an error?

Comment: Are you using this library? https://github.com/bilibili/flv.js/blob/master/docs/api.md

Comment: Yes, I tried enclosing the code in a try catch and it still crashes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This type of error (`Unhandled Rejection`) tells us you have a rejected Promise that is not being properly handled.

Promises are asynchronous, and the error will happen asynchronously as well.

According to the library documentation ([here](https://github.com/bilibili/flv.js/blob/master/docs/api.md#interface-player-abstract)), the only method that returns a Promise is method `play`.

So I guess that you are probably invoking `play` method in a different part of your code. And you need to capture the error there, as in:

```
flvPlayer.play().catch((e)=>{
   /* error handler */
})
```

Comment: I actually didn't invoke play, only load, I let the user click play. Strange...

Comment: I've never used this library, but this error is certainly related to a unhandled rejected promise. Maybe this is happening internally in the library.

I was taking a look on their docs and it seems there is another way to catch these errors via events:
`flvPlayer.on(flvjs.Events.ERROR, (errorType, errorDetail, errorInfo) => { console.log('errorType:', errorType); console.log('errorDetail:', errorDetail);
 console.log('errorInfo:', errorInfo); });
`