HTMLVideoElement load() throws uncatchable DOMException
The following code sometimes throws an exception in Firefox:
try {
  videoElem.load();
} 
catch (ignored) {}

The error:

Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The fetching process for the media resource was aborted by the user agent at the user's request.

I think it has to do with Firefox not loading the video when the page is not visible, to save resources. This makes sense, but I would like to catch the exception and continue executing my code.
The statement is already in a try catch, but still the exception is uncaught. load() does not return a promise. How do I catch this error?

Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73959930/519413

I found that other question but I believe it is a different issue. It is about the play() function which does return a promise, hence the exception can be caught with .catch() or await + try catch

@Derkades You need better testable code. What was videoElem doing before you tried videoElem.load();? Was it already loading or playing a video file? Maybe expand this example code to reproduce your error when tested in Firefox. PS: What does Chrome console say about the try/catch error? PPS: I suspect the "uncaught" is inside the load function, so you cannot catch it, just have code that doesn't trigger it. Then you can Catch your shown Try code.

I think this is going to turn out to be a Firefox bug.  Do you have any way to reliably reproduce the error?

This happened for a video element without a source (removeAttribute('src')), but I've also seen it happen for videos with a valid source. I'm not sure when exactly this happens, I only see it if I have been away from the page for a while and then take a look at the console. The backtrace specifically points to the load() line which makes it so strange to me.

You should see my answer below. It tells exacly why, how and where the error is thrown. It also tells how to catch it and how to handle it if left uncaught... I don't know why there's a user insisting my answer is bad when his answer is misleading into believing this is a bug...

@Derkades I think @KLASANGUI is giving you a good answer as far as the Question is concerned. Why is videoElem.play().catch( /* ... */ ); not enough to solve it?

try...catch handles synchronous errors, and errors during the load() call can be asynchronous.
The specified error does not come from .load(), but from other methods. For example, .play(), which can generate errors in the form of promise rejection.
If you want to track these errors, the browser generates asynchronous error or abort events that you can use like this:
videoElement.addEventListener('error', event => console.error(event));
videoElement.addEventListener('abort', event => console.error(event));

Or you can add error handling to the methods used in your script. For example, to the .play() method:
videoElement.play().catch(error => console.error(error));


The backtrace for the error generated by Firefox definitely points to the load() line in the source code, not play().

You are right that the exception can be handled at the play() method, even though the back trace points to load() as the cause of the exception

This looks like a Firefox bug.
I can repro this: first use a slow network to load a video. While the video is still loading, click the play icon from the <video>'s controls UI. Then execute OP's code.
This suggests to me that the culprit is that UI, which probably does call an equivalent of HTMLMediaElement.prototype.play() on the video element, but doesn't catch in case there was an error.
There is no way (I know of) to capture the actual click event on that UI. However listening for the play event brings us right in the good place, might be useful depending on how you plan to act on that issue.
We can actually catch that rejection, by listening for the global unhandledrejection event, but unlike other such events, preventing this one does not prevent its message being displayed in the console... And I couldn't find another way to do so, short of not calling load() when the networkState is  NETWORK_LOADING, but that's probably not what you want.
We can also detect that this happened by listening to the abort event, which would also fire in other browsers in such circumstances.


const vid = document.querySelector("video");

vid.addEventListener("play",  (evt) => {
  vid.load();
}, { once: true });

// Catch it like any other unhandled promise rejection
addEventListener("unhandledrejection", (evt) => {
  console.log(evt.reason);
  evt.preventDefault(); // does not prevent the message in the console...
});

// We can also know that something went bad from here
vid.addEventListener("abort", e => console.log("aborted"));
<h4>Click the play icon of the below &lt;video> in less than 5s</h4>
<video controls>
  <source src="https://app.requestly.io/delay/5000/https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a4/BBH_gravitational_lensing_of_gw150914.webm?">
</video>



Arguably, it might still be useful to have that error message in the console, since something didn't go well, but being able to catch it in the unhandledrejection while not being able to prevent the error message seems wrong, so you might want to open an issue.

Nice digging, as always, Kaiido.  :-)

It's important to notice that it's not videoElem.load() that is directly causing that uncaught error.
As per the usage notes of HTMLMediaElement.prototype.load() documentation:

Calling load() aborts all ongoing operations involving this media element [...]
The process of aborting any ongoing activities will cause any outstanding Promises returned by play() being fulfilled or rejected as appropriate based on their status before the loading of new media can begin. Pending play promises are aborted with an "AbortError" DOMException.

So, if you need to catch this error like in a try/catch, you should be looking for the .play() promise...
videoElem.play().catch( /* ... */ );

If the error is thrown by an event, like a user click on the play button provided by the user agent which you can't access, the only option I know of is handling by listening to unhandled errors. And that's exactly because as you can't access the user agent provided UI, you also can't access the play button to replace it's click event to prevent a default .play() and catch the error with a custom .play().catch(/* ... */).
You can actually get all unhandled errors if you initialize the error, unhandledrejection and/or abort event handlers beforehand in the window/(i)frame. Even those that happen in promises.


const errorHandler = errorEvent =>
{
  // Contains the actual error object.
  const errorObject = errorEvent?.error;

  // Contains the error message.
  const errorMessage = errorObject?.message ?? errorEvent?.message ?? errorEvent?.reason;

  // Contains the error stack trace if available.
  const errorStack = errorObject?.stack ?? errorEvent?.stack;

  console.warn
  (
    'Error caught:',
    {
      Message: errorMessage,
      Stack: errorStack,
    }
  );
}

addEventListener('abort', errorHandler);
addEventListener('error', errorHandler);
addEventListener('unhandledrejection', errorHandler);

console.clear();

// TEST 1 \\
new Promise
(
  ( resolve, reject ) =>
  {
    setTimeout(() => reject('The promise was rejected!'), 500);
  }
);

// TEST 2 \\
new Promise
(
  ( resolve, reject ) =>
  {
    setTimeout(() => reject(window[Symbol()]()), 500);
  }
);



NOTE that this must be initialized before any error might happen. If there's more scripts in the page that can throw unhandled exceptions, make sure they're run after the event listener implementation. Sometimes applying the defer property to other <link> or <script> tags that are not the initializer can help.
See more details in this other answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/79184566/2804429
HINT: Look for the messages in the browser console instead of the snippet console there.
FINALLY, I think the best solution for you should be avoiding the user agent provided UI for media elements and use a custom made where you can actually access all the promises and events directly.
Here's a shabby example of how you can build a customized control for your media/audio/video element:
function PlayButton ( mediaElement )
{
   const button = document.createElement('button');
   {
      // Customize your button with styles, classes, etc...
      
      // You can actually replace the line below with an image.
      button.textContent = 'Play';
   }
   
   const handler = clickEvent =>
   {
      const playPromise = mediaElement.play();
      
      playPromise.catch
      (
        error =>
        {
           // Your error can be handled here.
        }
      );
   };
   
   button.addEventListener('click', handler);
   
   return button;
}

// ...

videoControls.appendChild(new PlayButton(videoElement));

PS.: There's a pretty good discussion in the comments below.

@Kaiido Yes, I fully understood the question: "How do I catch this error?". And this is how you catch it. That's because it's not the load() method that throws this error. Please read my next comment that will complement this answer.

@Kaiido If you read the HTMLMediaElement.prototype.load() usage notes you'll see this: "Calling load() aborts all ongoing operations involving this media element [...] The process of aborting any ongoing activities will cause any outstanding Promises returned by play() being fulfilled or rejected as appropriate based on their status before the loading of new media can begin. Pending play promises are aborted with an "AbortError" DOMException."

@Kaiido So, .load() causing throws and rejected promises is to be expected as documented. It would be better to avoid .load() while playing any media. It's best to stop everything, handle all promises then .load() stuff. But if you want to catch the unhandled error, my answer (alongside yours) is the right way.

Your answer doesn't explain where the Promise came from and doesn't add anything to mine which already shown the far from perfect unhandledrejection event, and even fails to mention that this event doesn't work as expected in this case.

@Kaiido Now it does. I didn't depreciate your answer, but now that you did it to mine, I'll say this: it was your answer that suggested that this error is a bug, not mine. Yet, you're here insisting my answer is bad when yours misleads people... But thanks to that I could make my answer better. So, thank you?

The bug is that the Promise shouldn't exist, because play() wasn't called.

@Kaiido You don't know that. So, how can you say it so surely that .play() wasn't called? If the error was thrown because .load() is called, then it's because .play() was called before (or autoplay is enabled) and its promise failed to fulfill (by an abort or rejection). Just like the docs says... Now you're just spilling nonsense trying to downgrade my answer... There's no bug in JavaScript or any browser related to this because this error is expected. If there's a bug, it's in the OP code (that is not fully here).

Yes I know, I made a live snippet demonstrating exactly that...

@Kaiido No, you don't know because your misleading snippet is not the OP code. You're spilling nonsense again... Your live snippet just demonstrates that when you click the play button in the <video controls> UI the practical effect is the same as calling .play() that initiates a promise as per docs and dispatches the play event that triggers your handler that calls .load() which causes the promise to abort or reject. As there's no way to access the native browser UI controls play button, you can't .catch() the error from there. Yet, everything is happening as documented. No bug.

Having an observable Promise that wasn't generated by script is a bug. The zpecs don't ask that the play method is called, in fact it isn't as can be seen by overriding it. Another method that also does expose a Promise is called. It should not.

@Kaiido You're wrong. Even if there's no script on a document, every interactive element  in HTML will be handled by the JavaScript engine (DOM API). The HTML element will fire JavaScript events and any dynamic behavior happens at JavaScript engine context. So, clicking a play button in the media controls will fire a JavaScript event and will call the JavaScript media API .play() method (without even being scripted). "user interface features exposed by the user agent must be implemented in terms of the DOM API" from docs

@Kaiido To play the authority card you must be the maintainer... Are you? Or are you just some random dude that got thanked in the "Acknowledgements" section? Honestly, I didn't see your name there (which I don't really know because you use an alias here). To play this card you must first expose your credentials, or you're just some random. Also, the Web IDL is full of promise types that are observables. Look here and here. And did I ever said that promises are created out of nowhere?

I'm indeed one of the many contributors who are acknowledged in there. Nobody in this list is "random" though. But, I must admit you probably found a spec bug, in that indeed the sentence you outlined may sound like play() should be called. It is only in Firefox though, which would make it a specs bug. And no, the 2 links you provided do not expose Promises that are created by the engine. They all result from a JS call. Having one created from the UI interaction makes it come from nowhere, as can be seen in the wrongful trace.

@Kaiido UI interactions are events. So those promises/errors come from events and user actions, not from nowhere. Also, again, "user interface features exposed by the user agent must be implemented in terms of the DOM API" which defines the events which define that user interactions are events. So, if the user interacted with the play button by clicking it, the event click must be called, and the default behaviour of the click event is the .play() method of the media element. And here's from where the error is coming from.

I think this is the most plausible explanation. I indeed called play() elsewhere, without awaiting it or doing any error handling. Then when load() is called, the play promise is what returns an exception and Firefox attributes it to the load() call.

@KLASANGUI no, that's not what this sentence means. They meant to say that the methods should be called directly by the UA as if a script called these methods, so that the media events are fired as usual. Only events are fired from the UI interaction, and then they call handlers that have been declared by scripts, the event model does allow that. Not the Promise model which does rely on objects created from scripts so that we can listen to them resolve or reject. Having a lone Promise that can't be caught is a first to me, and looks very much like a bug.
